# Outputing the field as link doesn't properly show the field properties

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I want to output an image field as a link in a view. I've seen many tutorials but get stuck at one point.

I already added the link on top of the image field. By clicking on the image at rewrite results, I could check *Output this field as a link*, but checking it won't give me the fields properties where I could fill in the link field details, as shown in this screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Do you know what I'm missing?

These are the other view settings for that field.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: looks like bug and you can try changing the admin theme.

Comment: Have you checked the *REPLACEMENT PATTERNS*

Comment: Hi Bala, thank's - changing the admin theme has no effect on that. Even the replacement Patterns don't show up.

Comment: better you can post a bug in views issue queue page on drupal.org or try with fresh installation of drupal.

Comment: Don't you have "Replacement Patterns" under the "Target" input, where you can fill "_blank" ? You need to scroll a bit to see it. Do you have tokens enabled?

Comment: Hi Matt, no I don't see that. Tokens and Entity Tokens are enabled. I just see "Style Settings", "No Result Behaviour", "Rewrite Results" and "More". Under "Rewrite results" - if i check "Output field as a link" - nothing shows up where I could fill up something. Tried several admin themes. I think I miss maybe a module or sth.

Comment: Hi all - I've got it solved :) It is the jQuery-Version. With jQuery 1.7. the fields below "Output this filed as a link" won't show up. If you change the jQuery-Version to 1.5. it works!

Comment: @ChrisKlein post it as answer it will help the future visitors, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: https://www.drupal.org/node/1494860

Basically, upgrade to latest version of cTools and set the admin jQuery version to 1.5 via jquery_update.